# How to "desc" order group_by?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to `order("created_at desc")` the months?

The articles within the month are in descending order, but not the months themselves.

**controller**

```
def archives
  @posts = Post.order("created_at desc")
  @posts_by_months = @posts.group_by { |t| t.created_at.beginning_of_month }
end
```

**view**

```
<% @posts_by_months.sort.each do |month, posts| %>
  <%= month.strftime('%b') %>
  <% for post in posts %>
    <%= post.title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Is this as simple as `Post.order('MONTH(created_at), created_at desc')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Enumerable#inject` http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject:

```
@posts_by_months = @posts_by_months.inject({}) do |h,(k,v)| 
  h[k] = v.sort do |x,y| 
    y.created_at <=> x.created_at
  end
  h
end
```

For example:

```
irb(main):054:0> hash = @posts_by_months.inject({}) {|h,(k,v)| h[k] = v.sort {|x,y| y.created_at <=> x.created_at}; h}
#=> […]
irb(main):055:0> pp hash.first.map(&:created_at)
[Wed, 08 Jun 2016 22:26:34 UTC +00:00,
 Wed, 08 Jun 2016 21:49:49 UTC +00:00,
 Wed, 08 Jun 2016 18:30:44 UTC +00:00,
 Wed, 08 Jun 2016 18:25:40 UTC +00:00]
```

---

**UPDATE**

Works for Rails view via controller.

```
# app/controllers/website_controller.rb

class WebsiteController < ApplicationController
  def test
    @posts = Post.order("created_at desc")
    @posts_by_months = @posts.group_by {|t| t.created_at.beginning_of_month}
    @posts_by_months = @posts_by_months.inject({}) do |h,(k,v)|
      h[k] = v.sort do |x,y|
        y.created_at <=> x.created_at
      end
      h
    end

    render(:layout => false, :template => 'website/test')
  end
end
```

Using HAML (http://haml.info) template:

```
# app/views/website/test.html.haml

- @posts_by_months.sort.each do |month, posts|
  = month.strftime('%b')
  %br
  %ul
    - for post in posts
      %li
        = post.title
```

[image: Screenshot of "test.html.haml"]

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was looking for something though to add to the controller

Comment: I just updated my answer. I believe you could use in the controller—I haven't tested though.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com Just tested it and works in the controller. Updated answer with results.

Answer (score 1):

When sorting by month numbers you have to do some explicit conversions:

In controller:

```
@posts_by_months = @posts.group_by { |t| t.created_at.beginning_of_month }.
  sort_by { |k, _| k.strftime('%-m').to_i }.reverse

@posts_by_months.each { |month, posts| puts month.strftime('%b') } ;
=> Dec
Nov
Oct
Sep
Aug
Jul
Jun
May
Apr
Mar
Feb
Jan
```

Here `k.strftime('%-m')` extracts month number without padding as a string and `to_i` converts that to a number. Without the conversion `sort_by` will apply lexical sorting which is not what's required.

Result of `sort_by` is not a hash but two-dimensional array. This does not affect the view code though.

Comment: Thanks Nic! I couldn't get it to work though. The months are still showing in ascending order

Comment: Sorry, fixed the example.

Comment: What is the result on your side? I've added the example output, it is sorted by month number desc. Are you sure you used the version with `reverse`?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you are using PostgreSQL:

```
@posts = Post.select('extract(month from created_at) as month, posts.*').order('month DESC, created_at DESC').group_by(&:month)

@posts.each do |month, posts|
  puts "This is the month: #{Date::MONTHNAMES[month]}" 
  puts "And this is array of posts: #{posts}"
end
```